# How to calculate Covariance for a population not sample in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, covariance, portfolio

pandas is using "Sample Concept" where divisor is (N-1) as stated here
[cov method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cov.html)
while I need to calculate it for a population so divisor is (N) not (N-1).

How could I do this?
Currently, I multiply output by (N-1)/(N)

[Sample vs Population](https://www.macroption.com/population-sample-variance-standard-deviation/)
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OapgE.png)

Comment: then you just multiple the result with the corresponding number?

Answer (score 0):

It is an open request on [Pandas Github #28823](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28823). This means there is no answer in here, you may follow the case on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can get population covariance matrix like this:

```
df.cov(ddof=0)
```

The divisor used in calculations is `N - ddof`, and the default value of `ddof` is 1. So we will get sample covariance matrix by default.

Reference: [pandas.DataFrame.cov — pandas 2.1.1 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html)